# SVN - Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: linux, svn, google

I'm using RabbitVCS to work with Google Code, and I just recently started having problems with trying to commit. Whenever I try to commit, it says...

Commit failed

Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to Checkout request for (some file that is involved in the commit. The file it fails on isn't consistent).

I have no idea what is wrong, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else finds this useful, the solution (at least one that worked for me at svn@google-code) is to do a commit with complete authentication credentials on the command line, e.g.:

`svn commit --username me@gmail.com --password pass`

Also see: http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=4218

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was on Windows 7 while using Kaspersky Internet Security.

After switching the security off the commit went totaly fine.

Can be that other Kaspersky products have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a message in the error log of the web server. If you use apache, look for the right `error.log`. If you use standalone svn, switch to the apache module because standalone svn servers are poor error reporters. If you use something else, I don't know where the error log is.

Answer (score 0):

the error you're seeing is likely from some sort of transient problem within Google Code's Subversion service. If the problem persists, your best bet would be to visit [their google group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-code-hosting) and ask for assistance. Responses are generally pretty quick.